Conveniently serve static files from a repository?
Consider test.py:
import unittest
import os

import src.dl_latest_data

if 'PREFIX_OVERRIDE' in os.environ:
    PREFIX_OVERRIDE = os.environ['PREFIX_OVERRIDE']
else:
    PREFIX_OVERRIDE = 'http://localhost:8000/'

src.dl_latest_data.DATA_URL_PREFIX = PREFIX_OVERRIDE


from src.__main__ import main


class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_main_does_not_crash(self):
        main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

And gitlab-ci.yml:
stages:
  - test

run_tests:
  stage: test
  image: python
  script:
    - pip install -r requirements-dev.txt
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
    - python3 -m unittest

I want to run python3 test.py in my script section of gitlab-ci.yml and this will eventually download from the path specified in PREFIX_OVERRIDE. What's the idiomatic way to run an HTTP service that's going to serve files from within testcases directory?

While waiting for a better solution, I came up with building my own Docker container and publishing it in Docker Hub. Here's the source code:
Dockerfile
FROM python:3.13
EXPOSE 8000
ADD ./main.sh /main.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/main.sh"]

main.sh
#!/bin/bash

cd $DIRECTORY
python3 -m http.server $@

Now, relevant section of .gitlab-ci.yml looks like this:
run_tests:
  stage: test
  image: python
  variables:
    DIRECTORY: /builds/$CI_PROJECT_PATH/testsample
    PREFIX_OVERRIDE: http://httpserver:8000/
  services:
    - name: d33tah/python-http-server
      alias: httpserver
  script:
    - pip install -r requirements-dev.txt
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
    - python3 -m unittest

